# Firebase authWithOAuthRedirect() woes

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebasesimplelogin

I'm trying to update my angularjs app to support Firebase 1.1 (I was stick with Firebase 1.0.x).
It deprecates firebasesimplelogin, including authentication inside Firebase core.

I have been able to successfully implement authentication using

```
authWithOAuthPopup("<provider>", function(error, authData) { ... });
```

It accepts a callback, which is passed authentication data in `authData`.

On the contrary, I can't undersand how to use

```
authWithOAuthRedirect("<provider>", function(error) { ... });
```

[Firebase Authentication docs page](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html) is very concise... :-(. This is all what is said:

***Alternatively [instead of authWithOAuthPopup], you may prompt the user to login with a full browser redirect, and Firebase will automatically restore the session when you return to the originating page***

How do I get authData, when Firebase - after redirection - returns to my page?

Comment: Would `ref.onAuth(function(authData) { ... }` work for you? https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication

Comment: Yes! Thanks, that is the correct solution (if you want to post it as an answer...). Unfortunately, I have some additional problem (linked to a shortage of angular logic understanding of mine...). If you like, I'll detail it as an update to my question... However, it's totally unrelated with auth and/or Firebase...

Comment: If it's unrelated, I'd post a new question.

Comment: Yes, I did post a new question (here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406593/firebase-angularjs-ref-onauth-called-from-ng-init-cant-access-factory-da).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The authData is available by registering a listener directly on the ref (so before calling `authWithOAuthRedirect`).

```
ref.onAuth(function(authData) { 
    ... 
} 
ref.authWithOAuthRedirect("google", function(error) { ... });
```

See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication

Comment: I'm using AngularFire to do effectively the same thing (`$ref.$onAuth`, $ref.$authWithOauthRedirect`).  *after* the redirect completes, the `$onAuth` callback is not called and I have to refresh the page to be logged in.  The other answer provides a solution to manually reload the page, but I would like to avoid doing this. Any other ideas?

Comment: ^ same problem for me! Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I think I'm running into the same issue as you. I'm trying to do Facebook authentication.

First, I'd like to clarify the reproduction steps for my issue.

1. My app is loaded on the client.
2. User clicks login with Facebook.
3. ref.authWithOAuthRedirect('facebook', ...) is called.
4. Client is redirected to Facebook and Facebook redirects client back to Firebase app
5. Despite successful authentication with Facebook, the callback passed to onAuth() is invoked (only once) with authData === null.

The callback passed to onAuth() is not invoked a second time with correct authData.

However, reloading the app causes the callback passed to onAuth to be invoked with correct authData. The reasons for this are not known to me but I suspect race condition.

Here's my workaround.

Before calling ref.authWithOAuthRedirect('facebook', ...) set yourself a flag in sessionStorage.

```
sessionStorage.reload = true;
ref.authWithOAuthRedirect('facebook', ...)
```

When the client is redirected to your app back from Facebook, you should be able to check for this flag and reload the page if necessary.

```
if (sessionStorage.reload) {
    delete sessionStorage.reload;
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload();
    }, 1000)
}
```

setTimeout(function() { ... }, 1000) helps fight the assumed race condition. I found 500 ms is insufficient time for the race condition to be resolved.

And one small gotcha: if you reload the page too soon, then authData remains null no matter how many times you reload the page.

Comment: Thanks, this cured my redirect issues with Google auth.  I suspect that getAuth() is not synchronous/blocking in the redirect response.

Comment: I am looking at this problem as well. @Nikita did you ever find the reason or a better resolution than just reload?  I am also using ref.$onAuth before making the $authWithOAuthRedirect call, but I get the same results.   In my case, I am just calling $authWithOAuthRedirect as a second attempt after the first attempt did not set the authData.