# firebase 1.1.1 how to get twitter secret

Tags: javascript, twitter, firebase

Using the following javascript firebase version.

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

I need the `access_token_secret` to post on behalf of the user. However firebase doesn't seem to offer the secret access token.

```
ref.authWithOAuthPopup('twitter', function (e, user) {
  if (e) { throw e }
  console.log(user.twitter.accessToken)
  console.log(user.twitter.accessTokenSecret)
})
```

The console output.

```
##########-***************************************
undefined
```

Is it possible to get the secret access token through firebase auth?

Comment: I haven't switched to the new auth methods yet, but this might be what you're looking for: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication. I know your case is slightly different, since the `ref.authWithOAuthPopup` is documented to get the `authData` passed to the callback. But monitoring is what worked for OP here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26390027/209103, so it might allow you to continue until somebody comes up with a proper answer.

Comment: unfortunately still no secret access token

Comment: Hold on: you want to post to Twitter on behalf of the user? I don't think Firebase exposes the user's access token and secret to the application. From what I've seen Firebase's simple login just helps your application in identifying the user, it's not meant as a generic gateway to Twitter.

Comment: `angular-simple-login` gave accessToken and accessTokenSecret, the new firebase login only gives accessToken.

Comment: Hey there, sorry for the delay in responding. This is actually a bug in the login API. The old Simple Login API still exhibits the correct behavior. I have a fix for the login methods and will push it out to production later today or tomorrow. It won't require updating your client since it is a server-side fix. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @jacobawenger true thanks, pegged old versions for now. Congrats on the google thing btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this bug. This has been fixed! The response payload for the v2 routes now includes both an `accessToken` and an `accessTokenSecret`.