# I cannot get authData by using authWithOAuthRedirect with Chrome on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, firebase

I am integrating my project with facebook auth login, and I want to support Chrome on IOS. I noticed that I have to handle both authWithOAuthPopup and authWithRedirect ([firebase user-auth](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-popups)) in this case. However Chrome IOS did not support Popup auth currently.

I simplify my code and shows the case how it won't work in Chrome on IOS

```
    var rootRef = new Firebase('https://docs-sandbox.firebaseio.com/web/uauth');
    rootRef.onAuth( function(authData){
        alert('getAuth');
        alert(authData);
        console.log(authData);
    });
    $('#login').on('click', function(e){
        rootRef.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(err, authData){
            if(err && err.code === 'TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE'){
                rootRef.authWithOAuthRedirect("facebook", function(err, authData){
                    if(authData){
                        alert('redirect');
                        alert(authData);

                    }
                })   
            }
        })    
     });
```

Link here http://jsfiddle.net/blackbing/zjunuzec/5/ for more detail.

It works on Safari IOS. If login success, it will alert [object], but it shows null in Chrome on IOS.

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that I figure out what the problem is.

First of all, it is said getAuth is synchronized in document, but It is not reliable synchronized on authWithOAuthRedirect. So when the page redirect to the original page. I can't get authData so that I can't decide if user is signin. (but actually user is signed in). 
Second, since callback in "authWithOAuthRedirect" is not possible to be called, the callback function can't get authData anyway. It just could be called if occur error, right? I suggest to notice this behavior that in document.

Anyway: I think the snippet in document have to correct : 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-popups

the callback in authWithFunction is for handling error, not suggested to deal with authData, onAuth is a better way to get authData. I update a snippet on my gist [https://gist.github.com/blackbing/f77d04cbed4b0059af2e]

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com");


rootRef.onAuth( function(authData){
  //It is a better way to get authData instead of get from auth callback function
  console.log(authData);
});
// prefer pop-ups, so we don't navigate away from the page
// auth callback is to handle if occur error
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(err) {
  if (err) {
    if (err.code === "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE") {
      // fall-back to browser redirects, and pick up the session
      // automatically when we come back to the origin page
      ref.authWithOAuthRedirect("google", function(err) { ... });
    }
  }
});
```

BTW, I found a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/26416696/797411, the workaround is not good but I think we met the same problem.